# pandas groupby on columns

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I am trying following example, where I need to **group on columns**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (20,30)).astype(float),
                columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                    list(zip(np.arange(30), 
                             np.random.randint(0,10, (30,))))
                ))
y.T.groupby(level = 1).agg(lambda x: np.std(x)/np.mean(x))
```

and it works. However following returns an error:

```
y.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1).agg(lambda x: np.std(x)/np.mean(x))
```

Am I missing something?

---

Upd: Following works when take separately:

```
y.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1).agg(np.std)/\
   y.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1).agg(np.mean)
```

Comment: This seems like a bug. (I was able to reproduce for a different dataset that has multiindex on columns. Whenever you use lambda functions calling numpy functions it gives the same error.) Maybe try filing a bug report? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: I'll do it. Just felt I am bugging them too often ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `groupby` function is applied column-wise to your dataframe, however, when the dataframe is transposed, rows become columns and vice-versa.

This wouldn't be an issue if it weren't for the fact that your rows and columns aren't both multi-index. However, since you're treating your row index as a multi-index via the `level=1` attribute, you're getting that error.

Also if you're trying to group by rows, you should have `axis=0`

```
y.groupby(y.index, axis = 0).agg(lambda x: np.std(x)/np.mean(x))
```

Comment: the statement that "treating ... row index as a multi-index via the level=1 attribute, [leads to] error" is not true. It is functionality of pandas. Please see update. I do know the difference between the rows and columns (see the title of question). My question is what is the source of the error.